# The provider is spring data rest ,client is use feign with page not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, feign

my boot is 2.0.5
I have tried include

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
```

and feign code:

```
@GetMapping
PagedResources<Subject> findAll();
```

and replace PagedResources to Resources ,don't work.

and I also want to know the client controller how set the page param. can elegance to pass the controller param to feign then to the data-rest provider.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What Exactly does not work? If possible, provide git project to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data elements such as `Pageable` are not supported by Spring Cloud OpenFeign.  See [Support Spring Data Pageable in Feign Client](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/26).